# Calculate $|X|$, where $X=(A+A^2B^2+A^3+A^4B^4\dots _{100 \ terms})$

Tags: matrices, determinant

> $$A = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 
> 2  & -2 & -4 \\\
> -1 &  3 & 4 \\\
> 1  &  -2 &  -3 
> \end{array} \right]$$
>
> $$B = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 
> -4  & -3 & -3 \\\
> 1 &  0 & 1 \\\
> 4  &  4 &  3 
> \end{array} \right]$$
>
> We have to find $|X|$ where $X=(A+A^2B^2+A^3+A^4B^4\dots _{100 \ terms})$.

There must be something I'm missing. We can't evaluate each, and $AB$ was not even good. What can we do?

Comment: maybe try and see if $A$ or $B$ is nilpotent

Comment: you can at least try to multiply A by B and see what you get? (or get a computer to do it for you)

Comment: I have written that i found $AB$ not good. Maybe you try once again, if i have committed a mistake.

Comment: What is the pattern for the summation?

Comment: @Hurkyl This is enough, i hope. Andthis was what was given in problem. It's like for odd terms it's $A^n$ and even are $A^n B^n$

Comment: @exploringnet : Well anyways, even if you get $AB$, it's of no use because usually $(AB)^n\neq A^nB^n$ ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well actually, you can note that:

$A^2= A$ and $B^2= I_3$

This means that $\forall  n\in \Bbb{N}^*,\cases{A^n=A \\ B^{2n}=I_3 \\ B^{2n+1}=B}$

Now that means that for every even $n$, $A^nB^n=A$ and for every odd $n$, $A^nB^n=AB$

Oh and you only have even $A^nB^n$ terms, so here you go, it'as actually equal to the sum of all $A^n$ for odd $n$ plus the sum of $A$ for all even terms, so it's basically just $X=100\times A$ so $det(X)=100^3 \times det(A)=0$ because $det(A)=0$

Answer (score 2):

First note that $A$ has determinant $0$ (for example, the second column is the sum of the first and third). Then we have

\begin{align*}
|X| &= |A + A^2B^2 + A^3 + A^4B^4 + \dots + A^{99} + A^{100}B^{100}|\\ 
&= |A(I + AB^2 + A^2 + A^3B^4 + \dots + A^{98} + A^{99}B^{100})|\\
&= |A||I + AB^2 + A^2 + A^3B^4 + \dots + A^{98} + A^{99}B^{100}|\\
&= 0|I + AB^2 + A^2 + A^3B^4 + \dots + A^{98} + A^{99}B^{100}|\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}